# MicroCharts on Xamarin.Forms iOS outside of ViewPort

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.forms

I got the issue, that the labels and values around a RadarChart (as well es DonutChart, PieChart, ...) are outside the viewport. Is there any way to fix it?

My XAML looks like:

```
<microcharts:ChartView Grid.Row="1" Chart="{Binding ChartEmployer}" IsVisible="{Binding EmployersChartVisibility}" x:Name="EmployerChart" />
```

and my ViewModel returns

```
return new RadarChart()
                    {
                        Entries = EntriesEmployer,
                        LabelTextSize = 50f,
                        BorderLineColor = Application.Current.RequestedTheme == OSAppTheme.Light ? SKColors.Black : SKColors.White,
                        BackgroundColor = SKColors.Transparent,
                        LabelColor = Application.Current.RequestedTheme == OSAppTheme.Light
                            ? SKColors.Black
                            : SKColors.White,
                        BorderLineSize = 4,
                        PointSize = 20,
                        LineSize = 8,
                    };
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can set a height for the microcharts in xaml. Here is the code:

```
<forms:ChartView x:Name="Chart1" HeightRequest="300"/>
```

In the viewmodel, you can set the LabelTextSize in a small size. Here is the code:

```
Chart1.Chart = new RadarChart() { 
               Entries = entries,
                LabelTextSize = 10,
                
                BackgroundColor = SKColors.Transparent,
                LabelColor = Application.Current.RequestedTheme == OSAppTheme.Light
                            ? SKColors.Black
                            : SKColors.White,
                LineSize = 15,
            };
```

Comment: Unfortunately it ignores the HeightRequest and 10 is way too small to read it - plus shouldn't it resize by itself?

Comment: No, the height has to be set. You use the grid and the grid should be set large enouth to put the chart in.

Comment: I will give it a shot once again. Thanks. ;)